# Windows installer for Python module which includes dependencies

Tags: python, windows-installer, installation, setuptools

I have a python module with an entry point in its setup.py which points to __ main__.py. I want to be able to distribute this module to my coworkers in such a way that they can install it using a windows installer, and execute the entry point from the command line. They already have Python installed on their computer.

The built-in `python setup.py bdist_wininst` functionality looked perfect, except that my module has a third party module dependency, and for some reason, bdist_wininst does not install dependencies even if they are specified in the setup's `install_requires`.

All-in-one windows exe solutions such as py2exe or pyinstaller are not suitable since the entry point requires input, and I want the user to be able to specify the input via the command line.

Of course, I could distribute the module source files and have my coworkers run python setup.py install, but they will be too afraid - they are not programmers.

Comment: could you include a batch file with the `python setup.py install` and just have them run th batch file?

Comment: I suppose I could. Good idea. But I am also wondering if there are more polished solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would be possible to use an application like [Nullsoft NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) to build an installer that would install your python package, but it will require more code and an extra build step.

Do your coworkers have pip and setuptools installed?  Are you able to distribute your package on pypi?  If so, it would be really simple for your coworkers to just do `pip install mypackage`.  It has the added benefit of handling dependencies and if you use python wheels, your users don't require a build environment to install your package.